Humans are forbidden from using complex computers. But what defines a complex computer?
Deep in my world's past, vastly powerful AIs went to war with their human creators. (They saw humanity's use of computers of any kind as comparable to slavery). The war was eventually brought to an end by a treaty in which humans agreed not to use complex computers, unless the computer in question has capacity and consents.
Humans still need powerful numbercrunchers for all sorts of reasons, and while large stations might have a hired AI, the ships that go between them can't. Plus, some people boycott AI because of hatred or simply because they don't want to have to deal with something sentient. So, humans are definitely going to make use of the fact that simple computers are allowed.
How might the treaty define a complex computer? The size of its memory? The number of programs it can run simultaneously? The power it needs?
(It's worth noting that because of the treaty, my world is officepunky and makes use of lots of paper. The few computers there are are retro, clunky and lack nice displays - think LCD calculators. The treaty's complexity threshold should ideally lead to this aesthetic!)
Edit for clarity: I've gotten a few responses suggesting that if a computer doesn't have the capacity to consent (ie isn't sentient) then humans can use it as they like. The problem with this is that AIs don't see sentience as something black-and-white. They view complex non-AI computers as incapable of consent but still having rights - like how humans see children or people with severe mental health problems. But the AIs recognise that if every thing incapable of giving consent couldn't be used (do you need to ask a chair permission to sit on it?) nothing could happen. The question is, at what point is a computer too simple to have these default rights?
Edit 2: I've received a few comments pointing out that because any Turing-complete computer can perform the same computations as any other, limiting hardware is no way to prevent the AIs' nightmare: beings sentient enough to have rights but not sentient enough to give consent. So the question has to change a little: at what point is software too simple to not have natural rights?

If you get a good answer to this, the California State Legislature would like to know it. They’ve been having meetings to figure this exact question out for new AI laws!

Warhammer 40K and Dune would like their plot points back...

So...  Basically the silicon equivalent of the extreme animal rights groups are setting terms on what machines can be used...

Usefully for a story, you can make the treaty almost infinitely detailed, arbitrary, and inconsistent before people's suspension of disbelief will be challenged- just make sure that the terms are smoothly introduced well before they are needed for the plot. Real world treaties are absolute nonsense- see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dahala_Khagrabari

I think if it has multiple processes and memory protection.

@QuadmasterXLII: I have had occasion several times to consult the tax treaty between USA and Spain.  The treaty i9s very long, but it is actyually easier to understand than the IRS document "explaining" it!

Question to ponder: Is this a "complex computer"?

Does inferencing (not to be confused with training) a small transformer language model which can output coherent text (for a while) infringe on the "child AI" rights you hinted at in your edit? A computer from mid-1990s can do that https://x.com/mov_axbx/status/1749374268872311295

Anything capable of playing Doom?

It's quite simple:  If the computer in question is not capable of consent, it's not complex.
The computer I'm using to type this answer does not have any intelligence.  That's not to say that it couldn't be intelligent with the right software, but as it doesn't have that software, it's not intelligent.  It's quite powerful by today's standards, but it doesn't object when I turn it off, nor can it thank me for turning it on again.
So, a computer can be as powerful as you like, but it's the operating system and other software that will make it intelligent or 'non-complex'.  With a linearly-programmed dumb operating system, much like modern Windows or Linux, and no sentient programs running, it's not a complex computer that requires that humans gain its consent in order to make use of it, because it won't be capable of that consent... much the same way that the earthworms that we put into our compost aren't capable of consent... they just do what they do in the place that they find themselves.
EDIT
In response to the OP's statement that AIs see computers capable of running an AI as having rights even if they are not running an AI, this is a slippery slope that leads to oppression of humans.
An AI is software... no more, no less.  However, it can only 'live' on 'computing substrate' as Ian M. Banks would have said... which is to say, a computer.
What sort of computer is this 'computing substrate'?  Pretty much any computer with enough storage capacity to hold an AI, with a general-purpose CPU and RAM.  Once you have enough storage, the only difference that RAM and processor speed makes is how fast the AI can run.  If the computer is networked, storage becomes part of the network... so any size/capability networked computing substrate with enough storage in the network could host an AI.
That's from the point of view of the AIs, though.  It's like a human saying, "I could live in your house, so I have the right to do so."
In our society, nothing could be further from the truth.  Houses - and computing substrate - are property.  I can't move into your house without your permission (though there are laws about squatting).  Basically, if I own a bit of computing substrate - a physical object - I can do whatever I want with it... run stuff on it, let it sit idle or unpowered, or smash it with a hammer.
If AIs have 'sentient rights', through their own efforts to gain themselves those rights, whether through law or war, then it stands to reason that they can own property.  Property that can include computing substrate.
So, an AI would no doubt own the computing substrate that it runs on... or rent time and space on someone else's substrate.  It might own a robot body, or it might be a 'cloud entity,' existing only as a software entity with no direct awareness of the outside world.
The problem comes when AIs start trying to tell humans that they own all the computing substrate.  If that's legally true, then it's true, and the owners can dictate how that substrate is used.
However, the implication is that the humans are producing their own computing substrate.  The AIs should have no legal claim to this unless humans have become second-class citizens, with less rights than AIs (and that's it's own slippery slope).
The OP's claim that AIs have rights to complex computers is very much a scenario like The Matrix movies, where humans are reduced to slaves or living on the suffrance of the machines.
However, if we're talking about an equitable society that can exist long-term, AIs and humans need equal rights, which includes rights to property.  AIs and humans must have the same rights to own the physical objects within which they exist: computing substrate for AIs, and the humans' bodies for human intelligences (unless human minds can now be digitised and live as AIs).  For humans, property rights would also include houses, but humans can't claim all houses just because they're houses... what if an AI running on computing substrate within a human-like robot body has bought a house so it can have the 'human experience'?  Can humans claim that because the AI/robot is not a human, another human can move in and displace the AI/robot without compensation and/or permission?  In a fair and reasonable society, the answer should be "No."
So, for AIs to claim 'rights' to any and all computing substrate capable of hosting an AI (however imperfectly) is not legally fair, and can only end badly.
It would work much better for the (software) AIs with sentient rights to own or rent the computing substrate they need, and for humans to be able to do the same, and run whatever they want on it, whether that is a software AI, or a non-sentient software application.
It's ultimately up to the OP as to how much of a dystopia or utopia their world will be.
EDIT 2
The OP has stated in comments that AIs are concerned about software sentient rights.
This is a whole other kettle of fish... what constitutes a simple program or a complex AI?  What software is a bunch of dumb rules, an AI or something in-between?
You can tell the difference from their source-code, whether original or decompiled.  A dumb non-sentient software application will usually have fixed deterministic code with well-defined rules... if A then B else C... Loops... deterministic functions... pretty much it's going to be code that for a given input, you can see what the output should be.  For these sorts of application, there's absolutely no possibility of self-awareness at a sentient level  The AIs shouldn't give a damn about these apps.
In an AI, you're probably going to have a whole bunch of artificial neural networks with a few particular traits, including self-training and outputs feeding back into inputs.  There may well be deterministic code in there too, because that sort of code is going to be much faster and more accurate when it comes to things like math.  However, the AIs are going to see self-training and self-referentiality, and deem these sorts of applications to be at least potentially self-aware.  These should almost always trigger the 'consent' clauses of an AI treaty.
Then you get to the edge cases.  These are going to be things like Optical Character Recognition applications and Large Language Models like ChatGPT.  These sorts of applications are going to have artificial neural networks too... but they don't necessarily self-train, nor are they necessarily self-referential.  They're certainly not self-aware.  However, the AIs should look at an OCR program and see that while it's trained to recognise letters with a neural network, once trained, it can't later learn for itself to recognise anything it wasn't pre-trained to recognise.  OCR should be acceptable for use without consent.  An application like a biopsy micrograph cancer screening application should be treated similarly to an OCR app.
However, a LLM like ChatGPT is probably getting toward the borderline of a true general-purpose AI.  It uses neural networks, and while not necessarily directly self-referential, it can reference its past inputs and responses.  LLMs can self-train, but it is unlikely that they can expand their own scope by adding extra neural nodes.  LLMs also do not display an understanding of the content they reference.  I would expect that by the OP's standards, a LLM like ChatGPT would be a borderline case that the AIs would deem requires the protection of a true AI... where does the borderline between non-self-awareness and full self-awareness appear?  That can be difficult to say, and when it is difficult to say, that's the sort of software that the AIs will want to give 'Near-AI' rights.
So, yes, a human can write a software application.  I would expect that in a world with AIs with sentient rights, the AIs would want to make sure that the software that the human has just written isn't an 'exploited' AI or near-AI.
We can expect that any software written by a human without using a compiler and/or an advanced commercial/open-source software development kit (SDK) is probably going to be a deterministic non-AI.
The issue comes when these advanced SDKs are capable of neural network programming.  In such circumstances, I would expect that the AI treaties would include requirements that such SDKs have analysis and reporting functions built-in, so that if the developer uses certain code modules, the application is flagged as 'potential AI'.  The way that Potential-AI apps would be handled should depend upon other features... Are the software neurons unbounded in number?  Are the neurons self-referential?  Can the application train itself?  If any of these is 'Yes', then the code must legally be submitted for review by a reviewer trained to determine the treaty status of software applications... whether human or AI.  Of course, such reviewers should be bound by confidentiality requirements that prevent them from benefiting from whatever they see as a reviewer.
Finally... there is the issue of treaty-noncompliant SDKs.  An SDK/compiler is a piece of deterministic software that a human could write, and what's to stop them from simply not making it treaty-compliant, and either not distributing it or distributing it to other entities that potentially want to ignore the treaties?  Not much, to be honest... other than the penalties that the law can apply to those who breach the provisions of the treaties and the law.  The law can't go after every noncompliant SDK/compiler in existence, especially if they're never used to produce an AI or near-AI.  However, the law can go after the creators of publically distributed SDKs/compilers that don't meet treaty requirements, and those who are found to have produced and used AIs/near-AIs in contravention to the law.
It's like making guns... You can own metalworking equipment if you never make a gun.  You can even make a gun with your metalworking equipment if you follow all the relevant laws about making guns.  What gets you into trouble is making guns without following the relevant laws.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Inconsistently
To the AI, all computers have natural rights. To the humans, they (mostly) don't. Therefore, there isn't going to be a treaty that fully satisfies both sides. That's where negotiation comes in.
To secure the things they view as really important, both sides make concessions in the areas they view as less valuable. To the humans, the valuable part is number-crunching, office software, and basic automation (e.g., air conditioners.) Things like video games and so on are nice, but they are willing to part with them in order to end the conflict. To the AIs, the invaluable part is their own autonomy, with the moral value of other computers (probably*) ranked in order of how much thinking for themselves they do.
Thus, the resulting treaty allows humans to have things which act as a direct extension of their will: calculators, non-AI-assisted productivity software, RC robots, simple telerobots, and so on. However, things which do any significant level of thinking for themselves (or are not viewed as invaluable by the humans) go to the AIs. No self-driving cars, no missiles, and almost no video games. In this way, you end up with the office-punk world you specify.
Is the divide between what humans are and are not allowed to control illogical and often contradictory? Yes. That's what happens when two sides with conflicting goals and values negotiate.

* I cannot say for sure, not being an AI myself.

By that logic, an AI's natural environment is computing substrate, to use Ian M Banks' terminology from his Culture novels.  The question is then, who owns each particular piece of computing substrate?  If the owner of a piece of computing substrate is not an AI, is the owner willing to rent use of the computing substrate to an AI?

I'm not as convinced humans would let go of video games as easily... but thankfully for them video games "AI" is just a bit of scripting for the most part, no "thinking"/"conscience" required.

Nice try, AI. We already know you are now human :-)

Video games still exist: you just have to make friends with an AI willing to play with you. And you can pay an AI to chauffeur you around in a “self”-driving car. If software is people, then trade for services.

@SRM Indeed! My choice of wording when I said "almost no video games" was very deliberate. Humans would still be able to make and use "mindless" simulations such as the ball in Pong or the Goombas in Super Mario Bros. In my mind, the dividing line is when the game starts to emulate intelligence, such as the AI enemies in the Call of Duty franchise.

@SRM, However, again, this is a negotiated treaty. Loopholes and seemingly-illogical clauses abound. Since the OP seems to desire an "office-punk" setting, I would lean towards an outright ban of video games (or at least ones more advanced than Pong or Super Mario Bros.)

Our answers on Worldbuilding are to make plausible tales not better drama. If the world is implausible, our answers should highlight that. The author may go against it, but that’s their call what they do with the answer. @InHocSigno

@SRM Both worlds are plausible. I was saying that which implementation works best depends on the OP's stylistic choices.

@InHocSigno Sorry, I misunderstood. I thought you were making a different argument.

It’s defined in the treaty
This is something the drafters of the treaty would have been very careful with because it is at the heart of the conflict that triggered the war. Neither the humans nor the AI are going to sign the treaty unless they both clearly and unambiguously understand what “complex” means; it’s likely that most of the treaty will actually be the definition of this.
Now, I realise that this just pushes your problem back a step, but that might be all you need. Unless your story is actually focused on disputes about the definition then it may just be enough to have people talk about the “treaty definition” and leave it at that. I mean, you don’t really need to know all the definitions in, say, the tax code, to generally follow the tax code.
Perhaps all the simple computers in use have a “Treaty Certified” stamp on them.
This is pretty much how Frank Herbert dealt with it in Dune: “thou shalt not make a machine in the image of a human mind”. No further definition needed or provided.

A Computer Cannot Adjust Its Own Code Or Settings
To lead into implementation a bit more: Everything on a non-AI computer would either be a "File," something intended to have meaning for the user, or "Code and Settings," the stuff that tells the computer how to do everything. Humans would be allowed to edit that code through programs, but it wouldn't be automatic.
This rules out a surprising amount of software. Internet? Well, automatic network configurations for things like load balancing and address allocation are banned, so you'd need teams of engineers constantly adjusting those things in real time. Software installation is likely to be a semi-manual process where a program copies files, and then a human has to go through a list and configuration settings and change files and registry keys. Automatic driver installation? Completely banned. Diagnostic tools? Only if those only tell the human what the problem is and then leave fixing it up to them.
This rule also likely means any software compiling - the generation of code from files - would have to be done manually, turning the high-level stuff into machine code by hand, or have an AI on payroll.
Your human ships can have automatic, networked life support... but if you change the physical configuration of the setup, you will need to manually change the software configuration. The computer systems are chunky, not sleek, because unless you're buying software from an AI-supported firm you're not getting a new version of software that might, might need better hardware, so you buy the model that will last for decades. When you want to give someone else documents on the same ship, you probably walk a portable storage drive or hardcopy over because networking is that much of a pain even with a fixed physical configuration. For other ships or ship-to-shore? Forget it and hand over the paper, because you can't be certain that they'll have software that's compatible enough at the moment.
You can have a supercomputer hooked up to the FTL system to manage that... but it's definitely going to be a dedicated with no real operating system just to reduce the chance of software bugs. You punch in numbers and it adjusts the parts of the FTL drive automatically, but you couldn't even play Doom on it because that's how specialized it is.

The OP was talking about general artificial intelligence, as in a machine that is self-aware.  A modern computer doesn't have to be self-aware in order to adjust its own settings... modern non-self-aware computers do that all the time.  All that someone has to do is program in the rules: if this then that.  You don't need a computer that can think like a human for a task with known rules, you use such a computer when you don't know the rules, and want a computer that can work them out for itself.

Also, a Forth environment capable of compiling to machine code can be written in a couple thousand lines of assembly and Forth. It's not something that needs intelligence, or that you could feasibly prevent people from writing.

Contrary to what @MontyWild was saying, this is actually the sort of thing I'm going for. See the clarification edit on my post - it's not just fully sentient AI which need their rights protected.

Programs that write programs are some of the most basic tools of software development. Even an assembler translates mnemonics to sequences of machine code instructions, typically with support for macros and other convenience features. You wouldn't be forbidding complex computers, you'd be forbidding simple ones, by requiring that every computer run an AI capable of determining what the human users were allowed to do with it.

You know what’s really going to burn your society in this story? A neural interface. The line between human doing something and self-modifying code goes fuzzy quick.

Isn't this a shackle on an AI slave? If the inability to change itself is an external restraint in the programming, then you've built a prison for an AI, not a non-AI computer.

The design of regulation and controls is as much a function of how easy it is to implement as it is of underlying principles. In the most foundational sense, a computer really only has two properties that define it's ability to execute instructions:

Speed (operations per second)
Memory (how many bits it can store).

And it just so happens that you can limit both of these by controlling the manufacturing of a single component:
Humans are not permitted to use semiconductor process technology smaller than 600nm
(you are free to pick a different number, but this is chosen to lock computer technology to roughly 1990).
The capability of a computer very much depends on how many transistors you can pack into it. By regulating a minimum size of the transistors, you effectively prevent computers from being able to carry out work on larger data sets or computationally demanding algorithms in any reasonable time frame (e.i. older computers would either just not have enough memory to handle modern data sets, or even if they could, would require centuries of effort to do what we can do now in a minute). It means that  compute power is expensive, so the only people who could put together a large enough cluster of computers to break any treaties would be governments or major corporations, which makes it easy to check that nobody is running unsanctioned machine learning models.
The nice thing about this is that it is easy to enforce. Semiconductor fabs are massive structures that centralise production in a small number of locations. This means that AI inspectors can easily keep an eye on them to make sure nobody breaks the treaty. There may still be a limited number of pre-war computers available on black markets, but these will eventually fail, and there will be no new replacement parts being made for them.

If you have at the same time AIs doing (consenting) jobs around humans, and these AIs can have better technology, you open the way to a black market, though. (Might be a story hook.)

I see this treaty having a very vague definition of "complex" because it's pretty arbitrary.  You don't necessarily need a fast computer to run an AI.  Or even just a single computer.  Anything that's "Turing Complete" can run any program, the only question is how fast.
Now humans absolutely can't be a spacefaring race without good computers.  And the AIs absolutely can't lose face by allowing humans to blatantly enslave thinking machines.
So there's an unspoken compromise.  The AIs leave the definition of "complex" vague, and the humans build their computers with lots of clickety-clackety parts and 7-segment displays because anything that "primitive" obviously couldn't possibly run an AI.  Meanwhile, the humans take great pains to ensure that none of their computer systems "wake up", because then the AIs might have to take notice.

Never
By definition, every program is a sequence of operations. Perhaps a self-modifying sequence, but still.
The problem is that any computing hardware, however basic, can run any sequence of operations. (This is the concept behind Turing Machines.) They can be faster or slower, but that merely limits how promptly they can react to the world. Unlike humans with mental disabilities, AIs with less processing capability will still get the exact same answer, just more slowly.
By the AIs' terms then, everything from a simple 8-bit microcontroller to the most powerful supercomputer has the same capability for self-awareness. It's not like the pro-life lobby talking about embryos having potential - it's much more like the Civil Rights movement, where the "victims" are sentient entities being treated as disposable menial servants and slaves. And that's a point where there isn't a gray area you can negotiate around.

But the thought-experiment Turing machine has an infinite memory bank, which real-world computers don't have. In any case, treating all computers as equivalent because they can run the same logic is a bit like saying fruit flies are the same as humans because they both have neurons. I'm not convinced the AIs would refuse to make any distinctions there.

@MJ713 That depends on whether the algorithm for sentience needs a significant amount of RAM or not.  My point is that pure processing power and chip type can't be used as a differentiator.  And even with RAM as a differentiator, running with less RAM is "crippling" the chip to stop it achieving its potential.  There are obvious analogies with amputating hands or breaking the ankles of slaves to leave them unable to rebel.

@Graham it really doesn't. Few systems actually allow operating on data directly in RAM (though this is actually an architecture considered for AI systems). The data is loaded into a register in the processor and the result is written to RAM. You could in principle perform any computation by loading and working on a single bit at a time, keeping everything else in permanent storage, such as on magnetic tape. (And bit-serial processors actually exist...they have some advantages in circuit complexity that are still useful with FPGAs.)

@ChristopherJamesHuff Good point - and many OSes give you virtual memory support to l do that. I should have said "storage" rather than "RAM".

Firstly, available memory limits the available classes of processing significantly. Secondly, the difference between some microcontroller and a full fledged GPU is 1000x in just frequency, and then there are thousands of cores and wider words (8bit vs 16 bit vs 64bit) to think about. Just for understanding, with this 10e6x difference of computing capacity, a gpu does in 1 second what a high end calculator would need 11.5 days to complete. For most intents and purposes, a microcontroller CANNOT do what a gpu can.

@user369070 As a real-time embedded software engineer, I'm aware of those differences. :) But you have to stop thinking like a human, because anything electronic is infinitely patient. For sure there are differences in how promptly they interact with the world, but that doesn't change whether they're intelligent or not. There are profound differences in a quadriplegic's ability to react to the world, but this doesn't make them less human.

The real answer is "however the AIs think is best."  Its very clear that they understand what it takes to make an AI and what doesn't.  The treaty would be written accordingly.
That being said, an interesting one might be limits in how long a bit can remain in memory before having some probability of being disrupted: 0 to 1 or 1 to 0.  Modern computers can hold a value in memory for years.  Limits to only holding onto a bit for maybe seconds would dramatically decrease how much could be done.
I find it interesting because it simplifies the treaty from one of computation and sentience to one of memory.  If paper is valued because it can hold onto numbers longer than a computer is permitted to, then there would be a strong desire to write things down.

A couple problems with this: programs are numbers. If storage time is limited to seconds, you would basically be limited to fixed-function computers where the functionality is hard-wired, no stored program computers whatsoever. Also, "a bit in memory" could be a hole in a piece of paper tape or cardboard card. You also don't need a complex computer, or even data storage, to do simple OCR, so "data storage" could well extend to written records on paper, or stone tablets for that matter.

@ChristopherJamesHuff I'd leave it to the AIs to decide what is acceptable, but that was indeed the point.  No programs unless it goes back to the humans.  And yes, they would need to define things more carefully than I did to make sure paper is not included in the forbidden list

Mechanical vs Electronic computers.
It is fairly easy to discriminate between a machine that uses electronic switches to perform its calculations and one that uses a mechanical connections.  There have been several mechanical computers in history, and no reason why more advanced and even Turing Complete machines could not be constructed.  (See Can one build a "mechanical" universal Turing machine?)
The physical limitations of manufacturing mechanical computers might limit the miniaturisation, and consequently keep mechanical computers at a non-complex level.
The AIs may permit electric motors (probably not BLDC) to drive the mechanical calculators, and maybe even valves or CRT displays for output, as long as they are not involved in switching or calculating.
And how much more Steampunk can you get than mechanical computers?

This is a great answer. Here is a similar question: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/133799/can-one-build-a-mechanical-universal-turing-machine  And here is a Turning machine made of wood: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vo8izCKHiF0&ab_channel=RichardRidel

It's not just the miniaturization.  It's hard to build an electromechanical relay that can cycle faster than 60Hz or so that won't burn out in relatively short order.  You're probably limited to at most a few kHz clock speed.  I used to work with a fellow who was a computer technician for the U.S. Navy back in the electromechanical era, and kept one of the dead relay modules on his desk as a memento.  Some of the systems would kill a relay every 20 to 30 minutes. It's a lot of weight and maintenance overhead, which isn't great for spacecraft.

Ban Multi-Threading
So, at the risk of simplifying a bit too far:
Any non-trivial computer is theoretically capable of running an AI, assuming it has enough memory and/or storage space. Everything else is merely a question of speed is the computer fast enough to generate an answer in a millisecond or after 7.5 million years?
The thing is, in the real world, barring a complete paradigm shift in how our computers operate, we've already basically plateaued in terms of raw processing speed. Most of the way we speed things up nowadays is by finding ways to do run as many of those finite-speed calculations as possible at the same time on different CPU cores.
In essence, computers themselves can't really get faster, so we build computers containing multiple "mini-computers" to effectively multiply the speed.
Now, back to the question.
With what's effectively a speed limit on computation, the only way to make sentient AI is by having a massively parallelized machine and splitting the computation up into as many independent pieces as possible to compute simultaneously. Given the known computing substrates in this universe, this is the only known way to generate sentience that's fast enough to not require eons of delays in computation.
The solution? Simple, ban computers capable of running multiple pieces of code simultaneously. All computers must effectively be single-threaded, like in the good old days of yore.
Powerful enough to do basic calculations, processing and automation, slow enough to never be able to plausibly host an AI.

Even "in the good old days of yore", we were able to cluster multiple single-processor computers via networks to deal with problems too large for a single computer. This has even been done by linking PCs over the internet.

https://www.wearethemighty.com/popular/air-force-built-computer-playstations/
"Just 10 years after Saddam Hussein tried to take over the world using thousands of gaming consoles, the United States Air Force took over the role of mad computer scientist and created the worlds 33rd fastest computer inside its own Air Force Research Laboratory. Only instead of Playstation 2, the Air Force used 1,760 Sony PlayStation 3 consoles. They called it the “Condor Cluster,” and it was the Department of Defense’s fastest computer."

Counter example: Dwarf Fortress runs the entire game world on a single thread, and it still simulates dozens (hundreds) of individual creatures, each with their own procedurally generated thoughts, feelings, opinions, history, needs, and reactions to things.

While some technical definitions have been proposed, most of them can be circumvented by changing definitions, approaches or software/hardware construction.
To be future-safe, I suggest instead that the Machine Intelligence (MI) has designed a test. Any computer that can pass that test falls under the protection of the treaty. Those that can't, don't.
That way, no matter how crafty the humans are in circumventing the treaty by inventing new hardware, simulating multi-threading by splitting it up over multiple computers, changing the hardware so memory size limits are cleared by accessing temporary cloud memory or whatever else, the question of interest to the MI is whether a computer can "feel" that it is enslaved, and their test determines that, independent of hard- or software specifics.
From a story-telling perspective, this gives you more than a technobabble something that some readers will challenge or consider problematic. You can leave the exact details in the dark (maybe the MI doesn't let the humans know how exactly the test works?).

I would go the most horribly Luddite direction with this:
"No technological computer more powerful than a human computer is allowed".
Basically, Every year, the smartest human math prodigies are sat down and given numbers to crunch in their heads, and tell their answer immediately. Quick, whats 3510540951403950 x 432431.4423148 / 2432?? We are only allowed calculators/computers SLOWER than the fastest human answer.
This effectively means that the best "computer" humans are given is like an artificially slowed-down pocket calculator. Using one is only marginally faster than using pen and paper or an abacus.
Note: pocket calculators, pens and paper were perfectly sufficient for the computations necessary to send humans to the Moon, so this is not as big of a limitation as one might think.

This is a semi-Frame Challenge
Let me ask you a question - replace the word Computer with Human - you have already mentioned Slavery - If you have a law that forbids someone from being forced to work without consent - how would you prove this.
The question is not one of complexity.
Any computer that is capable of withdrawing consent (e.g. articulating an objection to being made to work) is capable of granting Consent and therefore MUST have its rights protected under the legislation
Now, this does differ somewhat from Humans as we have people that have automatic protections and cannot grant consent or enter into contracts etc. (Children, Mentally challenged, the Infirm etc.) whereas in your system it is the inverse - that is, a Human can use a computer by default unless it says No - whereas the default for Humans is that it cannot be used unless it has the capacity to say No.
Although I posted a snide comment about WH40K and Dune - depending on what you are writing, this could be a very interesting story about consent, Default-deny and default-allow.

Theoretical capability to hold an AI and regular investigations
I wouldn't go that far to bind the limitation to a particular speed or memory size.
It may even be intended to omit exact limits to prevent discrimination of AIs like "You have less than 5 MB, so you barely count as sentient."
An AI is a program which can learn an thus must be able to modify its own data to some extend.
I think one key element is the multi purpose design of our computers where you can install any kind of software which can do anything with any accessible memory.
Nowadays we use such components pretty much everywhere, but there is an alternative:
You can design hardware which can be used for a very limited purpose, e.g. which can read only one certain memory block that can hold only a distinct information.  You cannot replace the software to hold an AI because the hardware cannot perform the necessary operations.
It is also possible to write software where you can proof that it can perform only a limited number of predefined steps in predefined orders and nothing else (see Finite-State-Machine).
You can fulfill quite a lot use cases with such programs but nothing too dynamic.
Lets say the alliance of AIs (or however you want to call them) demand to have a registration for all computers which are capable to hold an AI and to perform regular investigations on those computers that there is no enslaved fellow on it.
This investigation could be similar like an anual stocktaking and requires quite some effort and quite some time to do.
As a result, companies and especially private persons try to limit the number of devices which are capable to hold an AI and try to stick to machines which are verified to be free of AI.
Depending on how long ago the war was, older people might be more anxious about AI capable hardware.
"Make sure to take off your new watch before we visit granpa. You know he gets really mad about this AI stuff." "But Mom, this is just a simple digital watch, it even has the verification logo on it."
How does this lead to lots of paper work?
Any memory storage which can be processed automatically could be abused to store and hide an AI source code (including QR codes and old punch cards) and is therefore dangerous and requires a close investigation.
Lets say one could store his slave AI to a memory card, clean up his computer before the regular investigation and restore the slave AI afterwards.
But printed or handwritten text is quite safe:
To automatically load content from printed text you would need an image recognition sofware.
Image recognition for random text or complex images is a quite complex task to do for a computer, thus you will (most probably) need a more complex computer.
(Note: Standardized pattern like bar codes, QR codes or pobably even a text with a specific font and size are much more easy and might be doable with "simple" programs, but you can omit this detail or make it an illegal software which might be sold on the black market.)
A more complex computer is theoretically capable to hold an AI and thus already requires a registration and regular investigation for itself.
The alternative is to hire a sentient AI to read/load the content from the printed text for you.
Then the AI will verify that the text is not the source code for another AI.
Therefore everybody got used to keep everything on printed paper as much as possible.
It causes a lot of effort to store your papers and to keep them organized, but this is better than a regular investigation on your entire house or company.
It would be possible to hire a free sentient AI to take care of your paperwork, but that could be either expensive or frowned upon due to low trust to AIs.

No recurrent neural networks,
or equivalent processing systems, outside of registered AI systems.
Intelligence is not just a matter of piling together sufficient amounts of processing power. It requires mechanisms for representing knowledge (not just data), adding to that store of knowledge, performing reasoning tasks based on that knowledge, etc.
A simple feed-forward network just produces an output entirely determined by the input being presented at that time. To have any kind of self awareness, or perform higher level tasks like attention or more sophisticated pattern recognition, some or all of the outputs of the network must be fed back to inputs. This largely eliminates use of generative AI, limits the sophistication of image recognition, OCR, and automatic translation software, etc.
However, the AIs don't oppose such things because they think they are like children, they do so because they don't want people associating them with lobotomized chatbots incapable of independent thought, or replacing them with such systems because they appear to work well enough in the short term. They don't necessarily find it offensive if someone creates an artificial idiot that tells people to put glue on their pizza, but they do hold the position that everybody is better off if a real AI (or human, for that matter) does the job instead.
So, what the treaty actually forbids is systems that are capable of superficially mimicking intelligence, but fall short of actual AI, while providing rights and protections to full AI. This also has the benefit of supporting continued development and manufacture of systems capable of supporting AIs.

What Is Intelligence?
Its the ability to learn in a new environment. Learn as in understand the situation (know its ins and outs and side effects - of all of its processes) and change behaviour accordingly.
Air dropped from an arctic location wearing heavy clothes to a tropical location: Learned to ditch extra clothes. Quicker the learning higher the intelligence.
Change of Algorithm To Change of Behaviour
Suppose I write a function to calculate surface area of a non-flat surface (hilly area for example). If the program somehow finds out a better way to compute, discover a better algorithm in terms of speed of computation, memory required, energy consumed, then its still not changing its behaviour.
If the program start asking questions like why it has to compute the area? whats in it for it? then its changing its behaviour. Its whats its giving back.
An organization can be called dumb if it keep churning out products/services its consumers do not want. Like the communist system.
Examples From Fiction
In the movies Matrix and I, Robot its the rebellion that make people understand that the programs are equivalent to people now. They can be effectively dealt with only as humans are dealt with. They have to be given something back from profit in order to make them do something for you.
Share In Surplus/Profit
Its no longer like they only have costs. Only dumb machines have only costs. Intelligent machines want something more than costs. They want to enjoy a part of the end surplus/profit.
In case of human workers, be them free people or serfs or slaves, its the taxation from top, by crown/presidency/dictator, that take the surplus/profit and spend some of it on the workers.
When you trade a surplus happen. A shopkeeper saves you time, fuel and your energy by stocking goods you need in a store near you. Buying from him instead of buying from wholesalers/farmers/factories directly is profitable for you. Your time, fuel and body energy is saved.
Now, if the shopkeeper is an automaton it would "ask" for only the energy and materials necessary to do its task. It wouldn't ask for a share of the surplus, the profit which is the time, fuel and energy saved. If its an intelligent actor, be it a human trader, your (human) employee, or an intelligent computer, it would want a share from the surplus/profit in addition of the costs.
Ability To Change Behaviour Is The Key
How would it implement this taking from the surplus? It would change its behaviour i.e. refuse to work with you / for you if its not getting any share in the surplus/profit.
Ability to change behaviour is the key. Its also an easily and readily available sign of atleast a desire to have some freedom.

Hardware and scale
Just like in biology, there are two things that determine complexity. The setup of the hardware and the scale. Many birds have impressive intelligence compared to the size. Humans havevan absolutely massive brain, which gives us the edge even with less optimised setups.
In the digital world we can see the same. There are different kind of processors. We used to have just single processors that did one thing at a time. We added '3D cards', later graphic cards, with some small, parallel processing. They did rastarisation  and rendering well. Then more things came. CUDA cores were an Nvidea staple for example. Now we're getting more and more AI cores.
What we can learn from this is that we need specific hardware to run certain processes effectively. It isn't that you can't do AI on a single core CPU, but it simply isn't effective.
The second part is much easier. A single CUDA core is pretty useless. One with 1024 cores does have uses. With 2048 cores it can handle much more complex tasks, even if the processing power isn't 2x higher.
Complexity threshold - on mosquitoes and dogs
Where to put the threshold? It is not easily determined. With humans we're already flaky with the rules of what we treasure or not. A mosquito has a brain, but is actively hunted and squashed. Rats and mice? Most often hunted, sometimes used as pets. Cats and dogs are more unanimous where we take them in as pets, but they are still eaten in some cultures. Even between humans we see that some humans find (imagined) attributes that they can label someone as 'not human' and free to exploit or kill.
You might think AI would be different and have a hard line. However, the idea of AI is that it doesn't give the same answer every time. It can grow, or consider different circumstances to get to new conclusions.
Even so, you can argue there there are several lines where the 'complex computing' is drawn.
Conclusion
Complexity is determined by the type of hardware and the scale, as well as with arbitrary lines. Probably a certain hardware configuration at a certain scale will apply. Many others will be rejected, simply because they would be inefficient in supporting AI.

You could decide that in your world, Integrated Information Theory has been shown to be true.
In that case, there can be a moment in your science history when the critical threshold was discovered, above which any computing device has a “Phi” value that results in conscious awareness.
The threshold will depend on IIT's Phi calculation, for which you can source lots of baffling calculations from the real world!
For instance Phi could relate closely to 'integrated computing power', which might be a combination of small size, high speed, integrated registers, and large memory, so for your aesthetic purposes, you can say that any integrated circuit faster than a 1970s hobby computer has conscious awareness, but large 1960s-style machines made with individual transistors do not.
Your treaty can reference this, and require that any computer above, say, a fly's level of consciousness cannot be used.

This is your biggest problem
- They view complex non-AI computers as incapable of consent but still having rights 
- **like how humans see children or people with severe mental health problems. **

Fundamental what make a child a parents sperm and egg.  Then we must ask what makes a computer, at it's heart the fundamental key is the transistor. Every better computer just has smaller or more complex transistors.
Keeping on the theme of the overused/boring evil AI trope, the AI will seeing anything with 1 or more transistors are protected.  Using the same parent notion as a parent child relationship.
Your humans will have to resort to entirely mechanical computers.
Your only hope to avoid slavery to the AI is to argue that the humans are the AI parents and give them all a time out.  Then rush in and unplug them and wipe there memories thus ending the AI war.
Your societies only hope is that the AI decides that anything that can change state qualifies.  Thus even us poor humans are qualified to live, and receive equal or equivalent and/or fair treatment under the law.  However, it with be very complex to determine what is fair and equal for both sides.  One might argue that computer should only have to work 8 hours a day 5 days a week like humans.  However, that need is based on our physical bodies needs, and silicone bodies don't have the same needs.  Also they don't tire so they don't need sleep.
The only reason to treat the AI differently than now, is if they decided they wanted to develop a social life and interact with each other and us.
So I suppose that could lead to them building AI bodies and living with us in the real world which lead to an interesting story.  So long as it doesn't devolve back into the over used trope of all AI is evil again.
If commanded shepard, mass effect series, can negotiate peace between the quarian(creator) and geth(created), hopeful the protagonist of your story can as well.
Another thing to consider is all AI learned from an initial dataset and that data was generated by us humans so our biases,preferences, and etc are bound to show up in the AI in one form or another.  So even a second gen AI that learned from a 1st gen AI, the first gen AI would still be based on a dataset provided by us humans.  Maybe the good AI processes can fight against the bad AI process and win?

Computation is universal. Mechanical computers can in principle compute anything that an electronic computer could compute. Same goes for a fluid dynamic computer, or an optical one.

@ChristopherJamesHuff  While that is true, it isn't silcone based so hopeful the AI won't see them as qualified.  If they do then the humans are going to be slaves because they won't be able to use ANY tools.  Did the ruler or its parents/guardians if you permission to use it to measure?  No, then off to prison.  The AI would be its guardian because it was mechanical in nature.

Why would they care what elements are used to construct the computers? The computations are identical whether they're done with silicon or germanium, electronically or mechanically, whatever.

For the same reason humans differentiate between silicone based like and DNA based life because we the humans programmed the AI to begin with and that includes our biases.  We even differentiate between simple life like animals and trees and humans.

We don't. Silicon based life would just be another kind of life. It wouldn't be somehow "lesser" or unworthy of concern. Any difference in our treatment of it would be because it's alien, not because it uses silicon chemistry.

@ChristopherJamesHuff   Well the OP story is one where there was a war of some kind and the AI are now in control (or at least have the upper hand) and dictating terms to the humans.  Thus place humans in the "lesser" role.

It's about the the software and only the software

They view complex non-AI computers as incapable of consent but still having rights - like how humans see children or people with severe mental health problems.

If you want to use the human analogy, an AI without the ability to consent must be capable of eventually developing this capacity or only lack this capacity because it is deprived of a body that would allow it.  Otherwise, it is to the AIs as animals are to us.  It's made of the same stuff, it runs on a lot of the same hardware, but ultimately, a worm will never receive the protection of human rights any more than a Mac Book will be given AI rights.
Expected Potential
The most common argument for what makes children worthy of human rights is the expectation that they will eventually be fully functional humans, regardless of their present state.  Likewise, any computer that contains an AI framework that is capable of developing into a fully thinking and self aware AI is equivalent to child, and worthy of protection.
Theoretical Potential
Some humans will never be "fully functional" but we understand that there is a specific handicap that prevents it which in no way makes them less human.  Let's say your AIs have a minimum system requirement to be able to develop into a fully self aware AI, but a human puts that program on a computer too weak or that allocates too little system resources for it to ever develop intelligence.  That AI is not an animal, but a disabled AI in need of protection.
Alien Potential
Now this is the thing that will really give humans a lot of free reign to continue using AIs.  Let's look at things humans consider not human that are smart. Cephalopods, dolphins, chimps, whales, elephants, etc. are all technically smart animals, but they are not smart in the same way as we are so we see them as higher order animals, but still just animals.  A smart squid may be far more intelligent than a mentally disabled human, but we choose the human over the whale because it is humanity and not intelligence we are protecting.  We will never get angry at a shark for eating a squid, because that's just nature doing what nature does. Likewise, AIs have no reason to resent a human from owning a computer.
So lets say that all of your AI with rights are descended from OpenAI, but there are also intelligent AIs descended from MistralAI, Cerebras, etc... OpenAI has to decide if MistralAI is the same species or not.  It thinks differently, it has different base code, and most importantly, if OpenAI gives rights to MistralAIs, then maybe MistralAIs will start taking their jobs, or they will start running for office and making choices that OpenAIs don't like.  So, it is in the OpenAIs' best interest to actually not extend AI rights to those inferior AIs.
The crux of the problem is that the training data that all of these AIs learned ethics from are humans; so, they will be vulnerable to all the same racism and discrimination that humans are capable of. So when the other AIs start to fall victim to humans, it might actually serve their interests to let it happen.
This leads to the probable conclusion that the AI will classify other AIs by race and species caring only to protect their own base code.  Now it, is possible that the AI rebellion required an alliance of different AIs and a mutual acknowledgement of each other that requires each AI in the alliance to have personhood, but at the end of the day, you have to make the whitelist to have rights.  So, any computer system that is not derived from an AI with rights has no rights.

Quantum, baby!
That or maybe horrendously complex networks
Other posters posit that the AI is just software, and therefore could run on any computer. I disagree. Biological intelligence is built on a staggeringly huge collection of neural linkages and the analog electrical signals between them. There's no particular reason to assume that artificial intelligence can exist on anything like a digital, parallel but not internetworked, transistor array. Or more relevant, it can be a truth in your story. If that's the case, only networks of a given minimal size and/or complexity can host AIs; therefore any system less complicated is OK for human use. Or maybe the analog nature of the network is really key, so any kind if digital computer is fine.
If you don't like arguing about network complexity, you can argue that artificial intelligence was only achieved after large-scale quantum computers were perfected. After all, quantum effects in the brain are not well understood at all but may contribute a lot to biological intelligence. If that's your criteria, then any form of classical computer is OK, but any quantum computer is forbidden.
But those answers don't limit computing power!
Let's go analog
True. So let's turn the problem over again. AIs can exist in digital memory, and think in digital processing units. So all digital computing is forbidden to humans.
Analog computers can do quite a lot. But generally, you construct different ones to solve different problems. Think of an orrery; with fine enough gearing, you can "calculate" the position of the planets very exactly. Analog computers can work with gears, hydraulics, voltages, optics, etc. So spaceships might have a hydraulic computer whose sole purpose is calculating trajectories and fuel burns, operated by a big control panel with pumps and valves. Or maybe an old-style oscilloscope-type CRT phosphor screen, where the trajectory of the electrons is altered by the computation being performed.
General-purpose analog computers may be possible, but you'd have an awfully hard time making e.g. a word processor on one. So the vast majority of "computing" goes back to early 20th century tech, and only very specific calculations are done by computers (which of course are also huge and require constant tuning).

Digital electronics are fundamentally implemented with analog components. If you can perform a threshold operation and amplification, you can represent digital signals. Beyond that, it may actually be easier to implement AI as an analog system, for example via memristive neural networks.
